# Variations not showing in second language (WPML and Woo Commerce)

Tags: woocommerce, wpml

The variation is not showing in the second language using wpml and woocommerce. I checked with the multiple site for this. They suggested to upgrade wpml and woo commerce multilinguial plugin, that is done. Still variation is not showing. There are more products that have been uploaded, so fresh installation is not possible. Kindly guide me to sort this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to translate all variation from WPML/Woocommerce Multilengual option, here you will have access to all attributes and at the button you have all variation to translate.